# webpack trying to include too many modules when using knex.js on AWS Amplify

Tags: webpack, next.js, aws-amplify, knex.js

I'm encountering build errors with a next.js app on AWS Amplify while it builds and runs fine on my local machine. Specifically, it seems that webpack is trying to include all of the various SQL packages that knex might use. The error message is

> Can't resolve 'tedious'

Since I am only connecting to a mysql server and have explicitly listed `mysql2` in `package.json`, I don't need the `tedious` module as it appears to be for MS SQL Server. Adding `tedious` to `package.json` causes the build to complain about `mssql`, which is yet another module I don't actually need.

Based on this [github knex issue](https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/1128), a workaround appears to be adding the various modules to the webpack externals config. The [next.js custom webpack config documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config) indicates that such settings should be in the `next.config.js` file. However, I can't seem to get the correct combination. Here is my `next.config.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
    config.externals.concat([
        // Possible drivers (and related modules) for knex - we'll ignore them
        'tedious',
        'mssql',
        // etc. with more modules
    ]);
    return config;
  },
}
```

Unfortunately the error persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that I just missed the obvious error that caused the config to not actually get updated. The value of `concat` needs to be assigned back to `config.externals` like so:

```js
config.externals = config.externals.concat(['tedious', /* etc. */]);
```

Someone upvoted the question so I presume it is useful to someone else.